# bash returning erroneous results after about 36 million lines when iterating through a pair of files - is this a memory error?

Tags: linux, bash, loops, memory, memory-management

I have written a simple script in bash to iterate through a pair of text files to make sure they are properly formatted.

The required format is as follows:

- Each file contains millions of ‘records’.
- Each record takes up two lines in each file – a header line and a sequence line.
- Each header lines consists of a “>” symbol, followd by a sample name (alphanumeric string), followed by a period, followed by a unique record identifier number (an integer), followed by a suffix of either ‘/1’ or ‘/2’.
- Each sequence line contains a string of 30-100 A,C,G and T characters (the four DNA nucleotides, if anyone is wondering).
- The files are paired, in that the first record in one file corresponds to the first record in the second file,  and so forth.  The header lines in the two files should be identical, except that in one files they will all have a ‘/1’ siffix and in the other file they will all have a ‘/2’ suffix. The sequence lines can be very different between the two files.

The code I developed is designed to check that  (a) the hearder lines in each record follow the correct format, (2) the header lines in the corresponding records in the two files match (i.e. are identical except for the /1 and /2 suffixes) and (c) the sequence lines contain only A,C,G and T characters.

Example of properly formatted records:

```
> cat -n file1 | head -4 
1  >SRR573705.1/1
2  ATAATCATTTGCCTCTTAAGTGGGGGCTGGTATGAATGGCAAGACGGGAATCTAGCTGTCTCTCCCTTATATCTTGAAGTTAATATTTCTGTGAAGAAGC
3  >SRR573705.2/1
4  CCACTTGTCCCAGTCTGTGCTGCCTGTACAATGGATTAGCTGAGGAAAACTGGCATCCCATGGCCTCAAACAGACGCAGCAAGTCCATGAAGCCATAATT

> cat –n file2 | head -4 
1  >SRR573705.1/2
2  TTTCTAACAATTGAATTAGCAACACAAACACTATTGACAAAGCTATATCTTATTTCTACTAAAGCTCGATAGGGTCTTCTCGTCCTGCGATCCCATTCCT
3  >SRR573705.2/2
4  GTATGATGGGTGTGTCAAGGAGCTCAACCATCGTGATAGGCTACCTCATGCATCGAGACAAGATCACATTTAATGAGGCATTTGACATGGTCAGGAAGCA
```

My code is below. It works perfectly well for small test files containing only a couple of hundred records. When reading a real data file with millions or records, however, it returns non-sensical errors, for example:

```
Inaccurate header line in read 18214236 of file2 
Line 36428471: TGATTTCCTCCATAAGTGCCTTCTCGCACTCAACATCTTGATCACTACGTTCCTCAGCATTCGCCTCTTCTTCTTCTTCCTGTTCCTTTTTTTCATCCTC
```

The error above is simply wrong. Line  36,428,471 of file2 is  ‘>SRR573705.19887618/2’

The string reported in the error is not even present in file 2.  It does, however, appear multiple times in file1, i.e.:

```
cat -n /file1 | grep 'TGATTTCCTCCATAAGTGCCTTCTCGCACTCAACATCTTGATCACTACGTTCCTCAGCATTCGCCTCTTCTTCTTCTTCCTGTTCCTTTTTTTCATCCTC'
4632838 TGATTTCCTCCATAAGTGCCTTCTCGCACTCAACATCTTGATCACTACGTTCCTCAGCATTCGCCTCTTCTTCTTCTTCCTGTTCCTTTTTTTCATCCTC
24639990        TGATTTCCTCCATAAGTGCCTTCTCGCACTCAACATCTTGATCACTACGTTCCTCAGCATTCGCCTCTTCTTCTTCTTCCTGTTCCTTTTTTTCATCCTC
36428472        TGATTTCCTCCATAAGTGCCTTCTCGCACTCAACATCTTGATCACTACGTTCCTCAGCATTCGCCTCTTCTTCTTCTTCCTGTTCCTTTTTTTCATCCTC
143478526       TGATTTCCTCCATAAGTGCCTTCTCGCACTCAACATCTTGATCACTACGTTCCTCAGCATTCGCCTCTTCTTCTTCTTCCTGTTCCTTTTTTTCATCCTC
```

The data in the two files seems to match perfectly in the region where the error was returned:

```
cat -n file1 | head -36428474 | tail
36428465        >SRR573705.19887614/1
36428466        CACCCCAGCATGTTGACCACCCATGCCATTATTTCATGGTATTTTCTTACATTTTGTATATAACAGATGCATTACGTATTATAGCATTGCTTTTCGTAAA
36428467        >SRR573705.19887616/1
36428468        AGATCCTCCTCCTCATCGGTCAGTCGCCAATCCAACAACTCAACCTTCTTCTTCAAGTCACTCAGCCGTCGGCCCGGGACTGCCGTTTCATGATGCCTAT
36428469        >SRR573705.19887617/1
36428470        CAATAGCGTATATTAAAATTGCTGCAGTTAAAAAGCTCGTAGTTGGATCTTGGGCGCAGGCTGGCGGTCCGCCGCAAGGCGCGCCACTGCCAGCCTGGCC
36428471        >SRR573705.19887618/1
36428472        TGATTTCCTCCATAAGTGCCTTCTCGCACTCAACATCTTGATCACTACGTTCCTCAGCATTCGCCTCTTCTTCTTCTTCCTGTTCCTTTTTTTCATCCTC
36428473        >SRR573705.19887619/1
36428474        CCAGCCTGCGCCCAAGATCCAACTACGAGCTTTTTAACTGCAGCAATTTTAATATACGCTATTGGAGCTGGAATTACCGCGGCTGCTGGCACCAGACTTG

>cat -n file2 | head -36428474 | tail
36428465        >SRR573705.19887614/2
36428466        GTAATTTACAGGAATTGTTTACATTCTGAGCAAATAAAACAAATAATTTTAATACACAAACTTGTTGAAAGTTAATTAGGTTTTACGAAAA
36428467        >SRR573705.19887616/2
36428468        GCCGTCGCAGCAACATTTGAGATATCCCGTAAGACGTCTTGAACGGCTGGCTCTGTCTGCTCTCGGAGAACCTGCCGGCTGAACCGGACAGCGCAGACG
36428469        >SRR573705.19887617/2
36428470        CTCGAGTTCCGAAAACCAACGCAATAGAACCGAGGTCCTATTCCATTATTCCATGCTCTGCTGTCCAGGCGGTCGGCCTG
36428471        >SRR573705.19887618/2
36428472        GGACATGGAAACAGAAAATAATGAAAAGACCAAAGAAGATGCACTTGAGGTTGATAAGCCTAAAGG
36428473        >SRR573705.19887619/2
36428474        CCCGACACGGGGAGGTAGTGACGAAAAATAGCAATACAGGACTCTTTCGAGGCCCTGTAATTGGAATGAGTACACTTTAAATCCTTTAACGAGGATCTAT
```

Is there some sort of memory limit in bash that could cause such an error? I have run various versions of this code over multiple files and consistently get this problem after 36,000,000 lines.

My code:

```
set -u    
function fastaConsistencyChecker {
    F_READS=$1
    R_READS=$2
    echo -e $F_READS
    echo -e $R_READS
    if [[ ! -s $F_READS ]]; then echo -e "File $F_READS could not be found."; exit 0; fi
    if [[ ! -s $R_READS ]]; then echo -e "File $R_READS could not be found."; exit 0; fi    
    exec 3<$F_READS
    exec 4<$R_READS        
    line_iterator=1
    read_iterator=1        
    while read FORWARD_LINE <&3 && read REVERSE_LINE <&4; do
        if [[ $(( $line_iterator % 2 )) == 1 ]]; then
            ## This is a header line ##
            if [[  ! ( $FORWARD_LINE =~ ^">"[[:alnum:]]+\.[0-9]+/1$ ) ]]; then
                echo -e "Inaccurate header line in read ${read_iterator} of file ${F_READS}"
                echo -e "Line ${line_iterator}: ${FORWARD_LINE}"
                exit 0
            fi

            if [[ ! ( $REVERSE_LINE =~ ^">"[[:alnum:]]+\.[0-9]+/2$ ) ]]; then
                echo -e "Inaccurate header line in read ${read_iterator} of file ${R_READS}"
                echo -e "Line ${line_iterator}: ${REVERSE_LINE}"
                exit 0
            fi                
            F_Name=${FORWARD_LINE:1:${#FORWARD_LINE}-3}
            R_Name=${REVERSE_LINE:1:${#REVERSE_LINE}-3}                
            if [[ $F_Name != $R_Name ]]; then
                echo -e "Record names do not match. "
                echo -e "Line ${line_iterator}: ${FORWARD_LINE}"
                echo -e "Line ${line_iterator}: ${REVERSE_LINE}"
                exit 0
            fi                
            line_iterator=$(( $line_iterator + 1 ))            
        else 
            if [[ ! ( $FORWARD_LINE =~ ^[ATCGNatcgn]+$ ) ]]; then
                echo -e "Ambigous sequence detected for read ${read_iterator} at line ${line_iterator} in file ${F_READS}"
                exit 0
            fi                
            read_iterator=$(( $read_iterator + 1 ))
            line_iterator=$(( $line_iterator + 1 ))            
        fi
        unset FORWARD_LINE
        unset REVERSE_LINE
    done        
    echo -e "$line_iterator lines and $read_iterator reads"
    echo -e "No errors detected."
    echo -e ""
}
export -f fastaConsistencyChecker
FILE3="filepath/file1"    
FILE4="filepath/file2"    
fastaConsistencyChecker $FILE3 $FILE4
```

Comment: If it is a memory error, is it possible to separate the file into two parts and do the processing then? Also, for data this big you might not want to be using bash.

Comment: Any idea what byte position in the file it's at when it gets the error?

Comment: I'm assuming (hoping) that you're running this on a 64bit arch? YOu might also want to include output of `bash --version`. Interesting problem, Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I think you've proven there's an issue related to memory usage with bash.  I think you can accomplish your format verification without running afoul of the memory issue by using text processing tools from bash.

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! [[ $1 && $2 && -s $1 && -s $2 ]]; then
    echo "usage: $0 <file1> <file2>"
    exit 1
fi

set -e
dir=`mktemp -d`
clean () { rm -fr $dir; }
trap clean EXIT

pairs () { sed 'N;s/\n/\t/' "$@"; }

pairs $1 > $dir/$1
pairs $2 > $dir/$2

paste $dir/$1 $dir/$2 | grep -vP '^>(\w+\.\d+)/1\t[ACGT]+\t>\1/2\t[ACGT]+$' && exit 1

exit 0
```

The sed script takes a line and concatenates it with the next, separated by a tab.  This:

```
>SRR573705.1/1
ATAATCATTTGCCTCTT...
```

becomes this:

```
>SRR573705.1/1  ATAATCATTTGCCTCTT...
```

The paste takes the first line of file 1 and the first line of file 2 and outputs them as one line separated by a tab.  It does the same for the second line, and so forth.  grep see input like this:

```
>SRR573705.1/1. ATAATCATTTGCCTCT....    >SRR573705.1/2. TTTCTAACAATTGAAT...
```

The regular expression captures the first identifier and matches the same identifier later in the line with the backreference `\1`.

The script outputs any lines failing to match the regex due to the `-v` switch to grep.  If lines are output, the script exits with status 1.